# XML deserialize to same object different element names

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to deserialize an xml to an object to use. We have created templates and would like to keep the xml the same standard if possible. The problem I am trying to figure out is how to look within a standard node in the xml and all subnodes are the same object type, just with different node names.

For example:

```
<Account>
    <AccountNumber>12345</AccountNumber>
    <Balance>12.52</Balance>
    <LateFee>0</LateFee>
</Account>
```

The Account level is always within the template, but everything below that is variable. Is there a way to deserialize all nodes within the Account level to be the same object?

```
Public Class AccountNode
{
   Public String Name { get; set; }
   Public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

Based on my research, it appears, they have to have a standard naming schema and then you can have an attribute to assign to the Name value. I just haven't been able to confirm that. If someone has a link that I haven't been able to find, or is knowledgeable and can confirm whether or not this is a possibility, I would like to know.

EDIT:

I have a much larger xml than listed above, so I'm trying to see how I can deserialize it.

```
<AccountNumber>
  <KeyWord Name="Customer Account" isRegex="False" errorAllowance="10" LookFor="Customer Account">
    <Rectangle>
      <Left>200</Left>
      <Bottom>350</Bottom>
      <Right>600</Right>
      <Top>690</Top>
    </Rectangle>
    <Relations KwName="Charges">
      <Relation>above.0</Relation>
    </Relations>
  </KeyWord>
  <Capture DataType="String" FindIfKeywordMissing="false">
    <Rectangle>
      <Left>200</Left>
      <Bottom>350</Bottom>
      <Right>600</Right>
      <Top>690</Top>
    </Rectangle>
    <Relations anchorName="ChargeSection">
      <Relation>rightOf.0</Relation>
      <Relation>below.-20</Relation>
      <Relation>above.20</Relation>
      <Relation>width.150</Relation>
    </Relations>
    <Regex>Customer account\s+(\S+)</Regex>
  </Capture>
</AccountNumber>
```

So with this one, I assume it is similar, but basically the Account Number node is the variable one and everything above and below it is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a surrogate `[XmlAnyElement] public XElement[] AccountNodesXml` property in your `Account` class to manually convert your `AccountNode` objects from and to XML nodes.  Marking the property with [`XmlAnyElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx) ensures that the elements will taken verbatim from the XML:

```
public class Account
{
    public Account() { this.AccountNodes = new List<AccountNode>(); }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<AccountNode> AccountNodes { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XElement[] AccountNodesXml
    {
        get
        {
            if (AccountNodes == null)
                return null;
            return AccountNodes.Select(a => new XElement((XName)a.Name, a.Value)).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                AccountNodes = value.Select(e => new AccountNode { Name = e.Name.LocalName, Value = (string)e }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XxafdH) which successfully deserialized and re-serializes the following XML:

```
<Account>
  <AccountNumber>12345</AccountNumber>
  <Balance>12.52</Balance>
  <LateFee>0</LateFee>
</Account>
```

Comment: That is great. I was hoping that I could build off of the answer to more of what we are looking for, but I am struggling a bit. I have a much larger xml that I am trying to deserialize and contains many levels. I will update my question and see what can be done. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I guess, is it worth it to even go this route or just change the names of the nodes to standard ones and have a name attribute.